# 2's compliment input and using vhdl library for signed input

Tags: vhdl, fpga, xilinx

My input data is 2's compliment and I designed the input is signed number and the all of operation is used signed number,the library i used ieee.numeric_std.all, but when i do ‘+’ an error occurred "found '0' definitions of operator "+", cannot determine exact overloaded matching definition for "+"". So I changed another to another library ieee.std_logic_arith.all ans make the add operation as a component, it works.
when i simulate my code by using testbench, error occurred: Entity port xin does not match with type signed of component port.
I think this error is about my library.
can anyone help me ?

### new

i do not use adder as a component and the below code works

```
adder: process(clk)
begin
  if (clk'event and clk = '1')then
   if enable1='1' then
    add1 <= (x0(7)&x0) + (x15(8)&x15);
    add2 <= (x1(7)&x1) + (x14(8)&x14);
     add3 <= (x2(7)&x2) + (x13(8)&x13);
     add4 <= (x3(7)&x3) + (x12(8)&x12);
     add5 <= (x4(7)&x4) + (x11(8)&x11);
     add6 <= (x5(7)&x5) + (x10(8)&x10);
     add7 <= (x6(7)&x6) + (x9(8)&x9);
     add8 <= (x7(7)&x7) + (x8(8)&x8);
    end if;
  end if;
 end process adder;
```

and the library of my testbench use `use ieee.numeric_std.all;`

```
    USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
    use ieee.numeric_std.all;
    use ieee.std_logic_textio.all;
    use std.textio.all;

    ENTITY tb_signedinput IS
    END tb_signedinput;

ARCHITECTURE behavior OF tb_signedinput IS 

  -- Component Declaration
COMPONENT signedinput is
   port(   Clk : in std_logic; 
           reset : in std_logic;
             enable1 : in std_logic;
           Xin : in signed(7 downto 0); 
           Yout : out signed(19 downto 0) 
        );
END COMPONENT;

  --Inputs
   signal Clk : std_logic := '0';
   signal reset : std_logic := '0';
   signal Xin : signed(7 downto 0) := (others => '0');
   signal enable1 : std_logic := '0';
    --Outputs
   signal Yout : signed(19 downto 0);
   -- Array
    constant MEMSIZE: integer :=99;
    type testarray is array (MEMSIZE downto 0) of signed(7 DOWNTO 0);
   signal testvectors: testarray;

   shared variable vectornum,outnum: integer;

   -- Clock period definitions
constant Clk_period : time := 10 ns;

BEGIN

  -- Component Instantiation
 uut: signedinput PORT MAP(  Clk => Clk,
                             reset => reset,
                             Xin => Xin,
                                      enable1 =>enable1,
                             Yout => Yout   );
```

the error still occur:

```
Entity port xin does not match with type std_logic_vector of component port
Entity port yout does not match with type std_logic_vector of component port
```

therefore, I changed my adder again to

```
add1 <= resize(x0,9) + x15;
```

syntax good but same error in testbench..

Is error about my ISE type or library type?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your addition expression in `adder1` is invalid because you're trying to index element "8" when the range of `a1` and `a2` is 7 downto 0.

Assuming thet you're trying to sign extend it would look something more like this:

```vhdl
q <=(a1(7)&a1 + a2(7)&a2);
```

The "+" operator has higher precedence than "&" so you are trying to add `a1 + a2(7)` which is `signed + std_logic`. This doesn't have an overload defined in `numeric_std` in addition to being logically wrong.

This works:

```vhdl
q <=(a1(7)&a1) + (a2(7)&a2);
```

But it isn't the canonical way to implement sign extension when using `numeric_std`. You only need the left side term to have the same size as `q`. The signed "+" operator will take care of sign extending its right hand side automatically.

```vhdl
q <= resize(a1, q'length) + a2; -- Sign extend a1 and add
```

This gives cleaner code that says what it's doing without relying on the non-standard `std_logic_arith`.

The actual error about the type mismatch on `xin` isn't apparent from your code. It is possible that you have an older version of `signedinput` compiled with a different type on its port and haven't updated the library.

Comment: I do not use adder as components and changed my adder to  add1 <= (x0(7)&x0) + (x15(8)&x15); it works. therefore no use ieee. std_logic_arith.all; in my code, but the testbench still has same error..     thank you for your helping

Answer (score 0):

Kevin made it look tough, so I figured I'd show something that makes for a good explanation:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity adder1 is
    port ( 
        a1:         in   signed (7 downto 0);
        a2:         in   signed (7 downto 0);
        clk:        in   std_logic;
        enable1:    in   std_logic;
        q:          out  signed (8 downto 0)
    );
end entity;


architecture behavioral of adder1 is

begin
UNLABELLED:
    process(clk)
    begin 
        if clk'event and clk ='1' then 
            if enable1 = '1' then
                q <= a1(7) & a1 + a2 ;
            end if;
        end if;
        end process;
end architecture;
```

The assignment to `q` looks naked so it's worth explaining.
The "+" in numeric_std for signed will sign extend the shorter operand to match the length of the longer operand.

The rest is priority magic.

"+" and "&" are the same priority, which means they're evaluated in left to right *textual* order, meaning the sign extension with the concatenation operator is performed first (see IEEE Std 1076-2008, 9.2 Operators).

The "+" operator sees the left operand as longer and matches the right operand to it's length, (see package numeric_std "+" for L,R: signed). It does this by using signed RESIZE on both operands after finding the MAX of the length of both, along with converting metavalues to 'X's.

It works if the right operand is longer too:

```
        q <= a1 + (a2(7) & a2) ;
```

And here we need parentheses to associate the result of the concatenation operator as the right operand of the adding operator, because the two operators are the same priority and would otherwise be encountered in textual order.

There's no reason to call resize yet again, it's only a one bit sign extension by concatenation, based on knowing the sign is embodied in the left hand element (bit) of a two's compliment number.

The term canonical is not found in the VHDL standard.

As far as Xin, I'd agree with Kevin, something likely needs to be reanalyzed so that both references to signed are found in the same package.

Each declaration used in a design is unique. If say the actual in the port map depends on the type signed declaration in package std_logic_arith and the formal were to depend on the declaration of signed in package numeric_std they would be of different types.

Comment: I change the library to ieee.numeric_std.all and do not use component for adder, then syntax successful. Therefore, there is no library ieee.ats_logic_arith.all; but in my testbench the error" Entity port xin does not match with type signed of component port" still appear. is problem about library type?

Comment: which package are you using in your test bench? It wants to be the same.